# Manipulating lines in a text file

Tags: bash, perl, unix

I have a text file with the following:

```
1234  ^Y DATA ^Y DATA
1235  ^Y DATA ^Y DATA
1236  ^Y DATA ^Y DATA
/text text
/more text
1237  ^Y DATA ^Y DATA
```

Line numbers 4 and 5 belong at the end of line 3, but they are written as newlines in the text file. Is there a way to append the previous line if it does not adhere to NUMBER ^Y, as well as add a specific set of characters when this happens?

^Y is the field delimiter in this case.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried?

Comment: *Stack Overflow* isn't a source of free programming effort (although there are always people who value their own points count beyond the integrity if the site). Sometimes, no matter how well you know your job, you will come across situations that you cannot surpass. Languages, libraries and systems always have undocumented corners, and there is occasionally a bug that makes nonsense of what documentation there is. Such situations can often be resolved only by  persistence and dogged refusal to accept defeat. It is in situations like that where *Stack Overflow* comes into its own.

Comment: But it doesn't look like you're in a situation like that. As far as I know you may be completely unable to write a line of code. If that's the case then please don't just take a chance on getting the attention of someone who will answer any question thrown at them for the sake of a few points. Instead, please do what you would if you needed any other professional advice: seek out someone who can help you and pay them a fair fee for their trouble. "Mates rates" apply only to a select few friends and acquaintances, and asking for professional help from a world of complete strangers is just rude.

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @out;
while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    chomp $line;
    # regex to check for NUMBER ^Y; 
    if ($line =~ /^\d+\s+\^Y/) {
        push @out, $line;
    } else {
        # append to the last element of the array
        $out[-1] .= ' *chars to add* '.$line;
    }
}

print $_."\n" for @out;

__DATA__
1234  ^Y DATA ^Y DATA
1235  ^Y DATA ^Y DATA
1236  ^Y DATA ^Y DATA
/text text
/more text
1237  ^Y DATA ^Y DATA
```

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '{if(/\^Y/){if(p) print p; p=$0} else p=p $0} 
    END{print p}' file

1234  ^Y DATA ^Y DATA
1235  ^Y DATA ^Y DATA
1236  ^Y DATA ^Y DATA/text text/more text
1237  ^Y DATA ^Y DATA
```

Comment: awk wasn't an option. If you're going to post awk solutions the please refrain from opening with *to the rescue* which adds nothing except to saythat you don't know Perl. You should also properly document your code and describe it limitations and usage on the command line.

Comment: for a new joiner, lack of `awk` tag may mean the lack of knowledge that it exists. `awk` predates `perl` a decade and much easier to learn. My answers here have nothing to do whether I use/like/know `perl` or not.  I definitely appreciate its `regex` capabilities.

Comment: Thanks for not flaming my first post on this site. I tried your command like this:

awk '{if(/\^Y/){if(p) print p; p=$0} else p=p $0}
  END{print p}' <MY_FILENAME>

I get:

awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: illegal statement near line 1
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1

I'll pay someone if it can be done correctly, because that is what I need.

Comment: it should work as is if you copy/pasted it into a bash shell with you input file.  If you're not familiar with CLI, perhaps ask a friend/colleague to get you started.

Comment: Perhaps the issue is because the delimiter ^Y is actually hex 19 in the file?

Answer (score 0):

Here we are using `s` modifier to check and remove the entermark before the not equal to number which is starting from the line.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $text = do { local $/; <DATA> };

$text=~s/\n([^\d])/ <INSERT TEXT> $1/sg;

print $text;

__DATA__
1234  ^Y DATA ^Y DATA
1235  ^Y DATA ^Y DATA
1236  ^Y DATA ^Y DATA
/text text
/more text
1237  ^Y DATA ^Y DATA
```

output:

```
1234  ^Y DATA ^Y DATA
1235  ^Y DATA ^Y DATA
1236  ^Y DATA ^Y DATA <INSERT TEXT> /text text <INSERT TEXT> /more text
1237  ^Y DATA ^Y DATA
```